Flutter error happened when deploying on GitHub Pages with Actions
When I first use Actions in GitHub Pages to set my own page, it gives me an error.
enter image description here
Details are as follows:
Run flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...                       3.3s
Running "flutter pub get" in pozxy...                           
The current Dart SDK version is 2.17.0-266.1.beta.

Because pozxy_web requires SDK version >=3.0.5 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
---- Log transcript ----
FINE: Pub 2.17.0-266.1.beta
MSG : Resolving dependencies...
SLVR: fact: pozxy_web is 1.0.0+1
SLVR: derived: pozxy_web
SLVR: fact: pozxy_web requires SDK version >=3.0.5 <4.0.0
SLVR: conflict: pozxy_web requires SDK version >=3.0.5 <4.0.0
SLVR: Version solving took 0:00:00.040767 seconds.
    | Tried 1 solutions.
FINE: Resolving dependencies finished (0.0s).
ERR : The current Dart SDK version is 2.17.0-266.1.beta.
    | 
    | Because pozxy_web requires SDK version >=3.0.5 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
FINE: Exception type: SolveFailure
FINE: package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 311:5               VersionSolver._resolveConflict
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 132:27              VersionSolver._propagate
    | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 96:11               VersionSolver.solve.<fn>
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                     Future.catchError
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 109:52                              captureErrors.wrappedCallback
    | package:stack_trace                                            Chain.capture
    | package:pub/src/utils.dart 122:11                              captureErrors
    | package:pub/src/command.dart 183:13                            PubCommand.run
    | package:args/command_runner.dart 209:27                        CommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 174:24                     PubCommandRunner.runCommand
    | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 159:20                     PubCommandRunner.run
    | package:dartdev/dartdev.dart 45:56                             runDartdev
    | /b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/dartdev/bin/dartdev.dart 11:9  main
---- End log transcript ----
pub get failed (1; ---- End log transcript ----)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

and I use flutter --version in my Terminal, it shows that my dartsdk version is ok:
Flutter 3.21.0-1.0.pre.2 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c398442c35 (3 weeks ago) • 2024-03-12 22:26:24 -0700
Engine • revision 0d4f78c952
Tools • Dart 3.4.0 (build 3.4.0-190.1.beta) • DevTools 2.33.1

I don't know what's wrong.
I want to know how to fix it.

please usestable channel on your side. you are using beta channel and on deploy server its different one both are not matching

Thank you for your patient answer. But there is one more question . That is I change my flutter channel to stable , But when I use git to push ,it said that its the newest ,how can I solve it to git push successfully

Can you check your local machine vesion for flutter?

I confirmed that my flutter version is stable. And I just re-created a repository. After submitting it, I still get the same error when running actions. What should I do?

I agree with the commenter suggesting you to use the stable channel.
I guess you are using the flutter-action by subosito? I.e. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/flutter-action
You can configure it to use a specific channel, or even a specific version (so you can perfectly match your local setup). Check out these examples, adapted from the marketplace page linked above:
With a specific channel
steps:
  - name: Clone repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v4
  - name: Set up Flutter
    uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
    with:
      channel: stable
  - run: flutter --version
  - run: flutter pub get

With a specific version
steps:
  - name: Clone repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v4
  - name: Set up Flutter
    uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
    with:
      version: 3.19.5
  - run: flutter --version
  - run: flutter pub get

Extra tip
If you're regularly running the action, and/or planning to pin it on a version rather than a channel, you might want to add cache: true to the action too, so that it will cache the Flutter SDK, saving you quite some time on repeated runs with the same version
